Why raising serializers.ValidationError() is causing UnicodeDecodeError?
I am creating a django rest API(with a ImageField) and it is working fine. But I want to add some validations to some CharFields fields. I noticed some unicodeDecoderError while added a validator or simply raising a validation error. Spent quite a lot of time trying to solve it. Any help will be appreciated.
Here is my serializers.py file
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

def validate_phone(phone_number: str):
  print(phone_number)
  if not (phone_number.startswith(("6", "7", "8", "9"))):
    raise serializers.ValidationError(
        {"phone": "phone number must startwith digits from 6-9 !!!"})

  if not phone_number.isnumeric():
    raise serializers.ValidationError(
         {"phone": "phone number should contain digits only !!!"})

  if len(phone_number) != 10:
     raise serializers.ValidationError(
         {"phone": "phone number must contain only 10 digits !!!"})


class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  start_date = serializers.DateField(format='%d %B %Y')
  phone = serializers.CharField(max_length=10, validators=[validate_phone])
  class Meta:
    model = Student
    fields = '__all__'

Raising a validation error is resulting a UnicodeDecoderError. Working fine otherwise.
This is my models.py file
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    ...
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    ...
    start_date = models.DateField()
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile/', blank=True)
    ...

views.py
class CreateStudent(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        students = Student.objects.all()
        serializer =  StudentSerializer(students, many=True)
        return Response({"data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        print(data)
        serializer = StudentSerializer(data = data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            print("\nThis record is valid.")
            new_student = serializer.save()
            print(new_student.id)
            return Response({"message": "Data saved Successfully.", "data": serializer.data, "errors": serializer.errors})
        return Response({"message": "Invalid Data", "data": serializer.data, "errors": serializer.errors})

I am sending the data using javascript fetch API with FormData() which handles the file formatting and encoding.
Here is the javascript file:
const form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const formdata = new FormData(form);
  const json_data = Object.fromEntries(formdata);
  console.log(json_data);

  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formdata,
  };

  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/join/", requestOptions)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error))

Feeling helpless. Without raising a ValidationError it is working fine, I just want to add some validations without any UnicodeDecodeError. I tried to test with postman and the result is same. I do not know how to proceed.
Where am I missing
here is the full traceback:
[05/Jul/2024 08:31:03] "POST /api/join/ HTTP/1.1" 200 316
Internal Server Error: /api/join/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lokes\Desktop\Dambaruu\Tasks\Week-7\.api\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\lokes\Desktop\Dambaruu\Tasks\Week-7\.api\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 220, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\lokes\Desktop\Dambaruu\Tasks\Week-7\.api\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 114, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\lokes\Desktop\Dambaruu\Tasks\Week-7\.api\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\response.py", line 74, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "C:\Users\lokes\Desktop\Dambaruu\Tasks\Week-7\.api\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py", line 100, in render
    ret = json.dumps(
  File "C:\Users\lokes\Desktop\Dambaruu\Tasks\Week-7\.api\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\json.py", line 25, in dumps
    return json.dumps(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lokes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\lokes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\lokes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\lokes\Desktop\Dambaruu\Tasks\Week-7\.api\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\encoders.py", line 52, in default
    return obj.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte


Don't make us guess where the error happens.  Please update the question and add the full error traceback message.

added the full traceback

error suggests that problem is with data received from browser, not with data send to browser - so it seems your browser send data which is not UTF-8 text. Maybe it sends text in latin1 or cp1250, or maybe it sends bytes data (file)

value FF in first byte can also suggests text with BOM (Byte order mark - Wikipedia). which has value FF FE for UTF-16 LE. And maybe it has nothing to do with validator. Maybe is only accident that you start using wrong data when you start testing validator. maybe you copy text from file which was using UTF-16 LE

I think that your problem is here "profile_picture" it's a ImageField, try this in StudentSerializer return profile_picture.url instead profile_picture because profile_picture.url return a string and not a ImageField instance
